# Insert javascript parameter in Laravel translate within sweet alert error

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to make an universal function to alert for required fields in a form.

I didn't find the correct syntax for this.

My code:

```
function alertRequired(field) {
    swal({   
        title: "{{ trans('alerts.error') }}!",
        html: "{{ trans('cv.required_"+ field + "') }}",
        type: "error",  
        timer: 3500, 
        showCancelButton: false,   
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "{{ trans('alerts.close') }}",  
        closeOnConfirm: true
    })
    // location.reload(true)
}
```

The response in browser inside Sweet Alert is this:

```
cv.required_"+ field + "'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use javascript in php code. php code renders a html response on your server and javascript executes on the client side. So you cannot mix them. More information about this can be found in [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/171210/153671).

You will have to add all possible translations to your javascript code and get the one you need from this list.

For example:

```
var translations = {!! json_encode(trans('cv')) !!};
alert(translations["required_" + field]);
```

This will render all translations under `cv` to a json object that javascript can read, and on the second line, you get the property of this object you need.